Method of images and dielectric conditions
what is the physical intuition for the mathematical boundary condition when dielectric material changes
for example those 2 conditions what do they mean
$$
 \epsilon_2 \ x<0\  \\ \epsilon_1  \ x>0\ 
$$
$$ E(x<0)_{||}=E(x>0)_{||}$$
$$ \epsilon_2 E(x<0)_{perpendicular }=\epsilon_1 E(x>0)_{perpendicular}$$
given an infinite wire with longitudinal charge density$ 
\lambda$ placed parallel to the z axis so that The wire intersects the (x,y) plane at the point x = d,y=0
For the domain x > 0 the dielectric coefficient is $\epsilon_1$, while for the domain 0 > x the dielectric coefficient is $\epsilon_2$.
for this question we used the mirror method to achieve  the boundary conditions and made some assumptions about what the field would look like ,the choice for the imaginary wires is a bit ambiguous to me

From the perspective of a x<0 observer, there is a  line charge that's in x>0 which has a magnitude different from its observed value in x>0, and that I can understand
yet from the perspective of x>0 I understand that the whole effect of the dielectric space $\epsilon_2$ can be considers as a line wire yet the placement is ambiguous to me  I would have placed it at a general x yet here they deduced it would be at -d

